# Regex to add string to beginning of every word based on condition

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string which looks like this

```
someString = "#3Hello there! How many #4candies did you sell today? Do have any #4candies left?"

lookupDict = {"Hello there": "#3", "candies": "#4"}
```

Now I want to replace every terms in the string `someString` with `#0` which are not in the dictionary `lookupDict`. I can't split by a space `" "` since this will make certain terms like `Hello there` appear as two different words `Hello` and `there` and that would never match my condition.

Now I know to apply basic regex that would add a `#0` in front of every word. For example something like

```
let regex = /(\b\w+\b)/g;

someString = someString.replace(regex, '#0$1'));
```

But that would blindly add `#0` to every term and won't lookup in the dictionary `lookupDict`.

Is there any way I can combine the regex with a lookup in the dictionary and assign the `#0` accordingly? Basically the end result would something like

```
someString = "#3Hello there! #0How #0many #4candies #0did #0you #0sell #0today? #0Do #0have #0any #4candies #0left?"
```

Note: Spaces can be considered as word boundries here.

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? What do the "#0" actually signify? If it's some sort of score, do you really need to count the zeros? Are you sure regex is a better solution for this case than template literals or string concatenation?

Comment: Why should "hello there" be treated differently than other terms?

Comment: @DhrubajyotiGogoi Hello there is there in the `lookupDict` So it shouldn't be touched.

Comment: So, if there is `#`+ digits, the word/word combination should be skipped?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes exactly..

Comment: Please check Hamed Navabian's solution, if it does not work I will share mine

Comment: One thing is still unclear: what if you have `#7Hello there` in your string? There is no `"Hello there": "#7"`, so ... what is the expected output? Or is it something you do not need to handle?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is guaranteed that what you see in the dictionary key will be what is there in the string.

Comment: Please check your requirements, I still feel a little unclear. I understand it that `#3Hello there Hello there` should be converted to `#3Hello there #0Hello #0there`, right? `{value}{key}`s should be skipped only?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes absolutely! By the way Hamed's solution is close but it doesn't work for a case. I have mentioned that in the comment of his answer. You may need to use it as a test case.

Comment: Please add the ***word*** definition to the question if you want answers to be updated. Right now, my answer works for any word that consists of letters, digits and `_`. What do you expect it to consist of? Allow hyphens? Apostrophes? Any non-whitespace char???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following logic:

- Build an array of substrings you need to skip that are concatenated `value`s and `key`s of the associative array
- Sort the items by length in the descending order since the word boundaries might not work well with phrases containing whitespace
- Compile a regex pattern that will consist of two alternatives: the first will match the array items (escaped for use in a regex pattern) enclosed with a capturing group, and the other will match the rest of the "words"
- When a match is found, check if Group 1 matched. If group 1 matches, just return the match value, else, add `#0` to the match value.

Here is the implementation:

```js
let someString = "#3Hello there! How many #4candies did you sell today? Do have any #4candies left? #0how #0much";
const lookupDict = {"Hello there": "#3", "candies": "#4", "how": "#0", "much": "#0"};
let patternDict = [];                             // Substrings to skip
for (var key in lookupDict) {                     
  patternDict.push( `${lookupDict[key]}${key}` ); // Values + keys
}
patternDict.sort(function(a, b){                  // Sorting by length, descending
  return b.length - a.length;
});
var rx = new RegExp("(?:^|\\W)(" + patternDict.map(function(m) { // Building the final pattern
    return m.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');}
  ).join("|") + ")(?!\\w)|\\S+", "gi");
// rx = /(?:^|\W)(#3Hello there|#4candies|#0much|#0how)(?!\w)|\S+/gi
someString = someString.replace(rx, (x, y) => y ? x : `#0${x}` );
console.log(someString);
// => #3Hello there! #0How #0many #4candies #0did #0you #0sell #0today? #0Do #0have #0any #4candies #0left? #0how #0much
```

The regex will look like

```
/(?:^|\W)(#3Hello there|#4candies|#0much|#0how)(?!\w)|\S+/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mw63av/1) (PHP option chosen to highlight groups green).

**Details**

- `(?:^|\W)` - a non-capturing group matching either start of string (`^`) or (`|`) any non-word char (=a char other than an ASCII letter, digit or `_`)
- `(#3Hello there|#4candies|#0much|#0how)` - Capturing group 1 matching any of the `lookupDict` concatenated value+keys
- `(?!\w)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is a word char
- `|`  - or
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars.

Comment: this works quite well. But for this case `let lookupDict = { "how many": "#3", "people": "#1", "by": "#4", "age group": "#2", "in": "#0" }
let someString  = "#3how many #1people #4by #2age group #0in mgf-ind"`, the final output is `#3how many #1people #4by #2age group #0in #0mgf-#0ind` . For the word `mfg-ind`, it should add `#0` to only beginning of `mgf-ind` so it should be `#0mfg-ind`

Comment: @SouvikRay Then there is a question: what are the boundaries between your "words"? Whitespaces? Then you need `var rx = new RegExp("(?<!\\S)(" + patternDict.map(function(m) { 
    return m.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');}
  ).join("|") + ")(?!\\S)|\\S+", "gi");`

Comment: @SouvikRay You are not providing feedback on what your word boundaries are and asking questions that all have been answered. Just let know what your word boundaries are. If not whitespace, use **unambiguous** word boundaries, `var rx = new RegExp("(?<!\\w)(" + patternDict.map(function(m) { return m.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');} ).join("|") + ")(?!\\w)|\\S+", "gi");`. If `\\S+` is matching trailing punctuation, you must define what a word is for you here. If a `\\w+(?:[-']\\w+)*` works better use it.

Comment: @SouvikRay You should update the question. Right now, it does not look clear.

Comment: yes my word boundries are white spaces. I will mention that in the question. Right now trying your solution for different cases.

Comment: @SouvikRay Then you should  use my second comment solution with `(?<!\S) / (?!\S)`

Comment: when I use your second solution, for a case like `let someString =  "how" let lookupDict =  { how: "#0" }` , I get `SyntaxError: invalid regexp group`. This means if `lookupDict` itself contains `#0`, this must be handled.

Comment: @SouvikRay I think you did not use the escapes correctly. BTW, what is the browser/JS environment? Is it ECMAScript 2018+ compatible? Probably you want the unambiguous word boundaries for known strings and whitespace boundaries for new words. I updated the answer.

Comment: ok but on running your updated answer in SO itself, it throws error. Can you check?

Comment: @SouvikRay It does not throw any error in my Chrome. **What is your target browser/JS environment**?

Comment: try running in Firefox or Safari. This is what I use.

Comment: I see in Chrome it works but in Safari or Mozilla, it throws error.

Comment: @SouvikRay I converted the lookbehind into a group, now, it will work in any browser supporting ES6.

Comment: oh great! So tried out this scenario, `let someString = "how many"
const lookupDict = { "how many": "#3" }`, the result that comes is `#0how #0many` against the expected result of `#3how many`.

Comment: by the way I appreciate your time and patience you are giving to my problem.

Comment: @SouvikRay And isn't that expected? Your string does not contain `#3how many`, so all words in `how many`  are treated as new words to be prefixed. I asked you [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60365460/regex-to-add-string-to-beginning-of-every-word-based-on-condition/60366744?noredirect=1#comment106786459_60365460) and you gave me a positive answer.

Comment: oh you are right! I commented out a part of my code. Let me try this again. Apologies!

Comment: thanks man! It works smooth! I have tested for various situations and it gives me expected output! I appreciate your time and effort. Thanks again!

Comment: I haven't properly gone through your regex. I just tested it. So if I do not understand any part, I will put a comment here. Is that okay?

Comment: @SouvikRay There was no sense explaining it until finding out the exact requirements.  I will now add the regex explanation.

Answer (score 1):

With this way, there is no worry for lookupDict key length or anything else:

```js
let someString =
  "#3Hello there! How many #4candies did you sell today? #3Hello there! Do have any #4candies left?#3Hello there! #7John Doe! some other text with having #7John Doe person again";

const lookupDict = { "Hello there": "#3", candies: "#4", "John Doe": "#7" };

Object.keys(lookupDict).map((key, i) => {
  const regex = new RegExp(key, "g");
  someString = someString.replace(regex, lookupDict[key]); // replace each key to the value: Hello world => #3
});

someString = someString.replace(/ /gi, " #0"); // replace each space

Object.keys(lookupDict).map((key, i) => {
  const regex = new RegExp(lookupDict[key] + lookupDict[key], "g");
  someString = someString.replace(regex, `${lookupDict[key]}${key}`); // role back the value to key+value
});

someString = someString.replace(/#0#/gi, "#"); // replace #0 for each lookupDict key value

console.log(someString, '<TheResult/>');
```

Comment: It is close. But if I have a case like `let someString = "#0how #0much” const lookupDict = { "how": "#0", "much": "#0" }` , then the result is `#0how #0how#0` instead of expected `#0how #0much`

Comment: If you wanted to use #0 in lookupDict, the algorithm has to change. That was better to tell this on the question. But if it's necessary we can solve it and edit the answer?

Comment: sorry my bad! yes it would be great if the answer can be edited.

Comment: So please edit your question and write each possible lookupDict and string!

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a function to `.replace` as second parameter and check the matching token in dictionary

I've changed regex to not include `#` in results

`Hello there` is problematic, how long can a single term be? max 2 words?

```js
someString = "#3Hello there! How many #4candies did you sell today? Do have any #4candies left?"

let regex = /(?<!#)(\b\w+\b)/g;

someString = someString.replace(regex, x => {
// check x in dict
 return `#0${x}`
});
console.log(someString)
```

Comment: it depends on the key of the dictionary lookupDict. So what exists in the dictionary key shouldn't be processed.